# An error occurs when returning rvalue of std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

Error case (***why does the destructor of class A will be called by twice?***):

```
class A {};
std::unique_ptr<A>&& get() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A());
  return std::move(p);
}
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> k = get();
}
```

Got the below error when running the above code:

```
test(32033,0x116d375c0) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee5398818: pointer being freed was not allocated
test(32033,0x116d375c0) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
[1]    32033 abort      ./test
```

Normal Case:

```
class A {};
std::unique_ptr<A> get() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> p(new A());
  return std::move(p);
}
int main() {
  std::unique_ptr<A> k = std::move(get());
}
```

Comment: you are still returning a reference to a local object, and so is a dandling reference

Comment: Btw, don't `return std::move`.